# User, post, and comment model in mongoose

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am making a forum app that is quite similar to Reddit. I am using mongoose here for schema design. I have some doubts regarding models that I have- **User, Post and Comment**.

- Does the schema look all right of all the models?
- In User, I want to show the friends on the user profile. Like when you go to his profile, there will be like **Friends(200)**, and when I click the friend list will appear(like Facebook, then on clicking you can access friends' profiles). I haven't created `Friend` schema, but does it needed actually?
- Question about comments. So far, I have the basic comment schema. What happens to the threaded comments or replies. How do I store them?

All the models that I have currently:

```js
const userSchema = new Schema(
  {
    username: { type: String, required: true },
    email: { type: String, reuired: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true },
    country: { type: String, required: true },
    friends: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Friend" }], // is it needed?
    posts: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Post" }],
  },
  { timestamps: true }
)
```

```js
const postSchema = new Schema(
  {
    title: { type: String, required: true },
    description: { type: String, required: true },
    user: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" },
    slug: { type: String, slug: "title" },
    upvotes: { type: Number },
    downvotes: { type: Number },
    city: { type: String }, // post will have a tag by the city like NewYork, LA etc.
  },
  { timestamps: true }
)
```

```js
const commentSchema = new Schema(
  {
    comment: { type: String, required: true },
    post: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Post"},
    user: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User"},
    upvotes: { type: Number },
    downvotes: { type: Number }
  },
  { timestamps: true }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

For the Second Question you don't need `friend` schema since `friend` is also a `user`.

Comment: so, it should be in the schema or not?

Comment: yes. you need to have it.you can use it like this. `friends: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" }], `.

Comment: So, `friends` is on `User` model and also refercences `User` model?

Comment: A `friend` is also a `user`. So you are referring a another `user` as a `friend`.

Answer (score 0):

For the first question, Why do intend to store all the posts of a user inside the User object as a `list of posts`, this would mean fetching 100s of posts even when something basic like `username` or `email` is required. Instead, you can place `user_id` in the Post Schema, helping to identify posts from a particular User.